# Pass error messages in Jmeter log during load test

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner, logfile

In Loadrunner, we can write an error message in the scripts so we can get that information in log files after running the load test.

Is it possible to do the same in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is generic, I would suggest you to use bean shell pre or post processor based on your need and write down pure java in a try catch method to handle your error. For a detailed view on the processors. Go through the link [How to Use BeanShell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the [custom logger](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FFWTutorials/) plugin.

Though, Pre/Post Processor can also logs the custom messages as suggested by Arjun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin JMeter function: [__logn](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn)

> The logn function logs a message

You have 2 optional parameters, level and exception/Throwable:

> Log Level OUT, ERR, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN or ERROR  No
>
> Throwable text If non-empty, creates a Throwable to pass to the logger
>
> ```
> ${__logn(VAR1=${VAR1},OUT)}
> ```